# How to make specifics apps password protected even after passcode in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, security, password

I have passcode on iphone but sometimes i need to give my iphone to other to make calls. I want to make specific things password protected, things like mail, sms, contacts and some games.

Is it possible?

Comment: Apps have to implement that on their own.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible either. Get a bluetooth headset and share only that for calls instead of your whole iPhone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible, sorry

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to get this functionality "out of the box", you can take advantage of "Restrictions" to accomplish what you want.

In the Settings App, tap `General`, then `Restrictions`. You can `Enable Restrictions` and then `Don't Allow Any Apps`. It's not as convenient, as you have to go through some menus, but it should work.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not tested this, and I don't know what it would do to existing apps.